# Example of a non-Kummer totally tamely ramified Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a DVR with fraction field $K$, and let $L$ be a totally tamely ramified finite Galois extension of $K$ of degree $e$ - ie, the integral closure $B$ of $A$ in $L$ is a DVR with ramification degree $e$ over $A$, whose residue field extension is separable and of characteristic coprime to $e$.

Must $L = K(\sqrt[e]{\pi})$, where $\pi\in A$ is a uniformizer?

If not, can someone provide a counterexample?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the statement must be true if $A$ is complete. Thus a counterexample must somehow exploit this lack of completeness.

Comment: Also basically by the quadratic formula a counterexample does not exist for $e=2$. Really, a counterexample should exist though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a cubic monic polynomial which is $p$-Eisenstein for some prime $p\neq 3$. Assume to that the splitting field of $f$ is degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (which is equivalent to the discriminant being a square). Let $K$ be that splitting field. Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be its ring of integers and $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime above $p$.

Note that $\mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a totally tamely ramified extension of DVRs (by Eisensteinness at $p$). However $K$ is not $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{a})$ for any $a\in \mathbb{Q}$: for $a$ a noncube in $\mathbb{Q}$, the splitting field of $x^3-a$ must be degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$ does not contain primitive third roots of unity.

One example of such $f$ is $x^3-13x+13$ at the prime $p=13$.

Comment: but $K$ has degree 6 over $\mathbb{Q}$, so it's not totally ramified (since the ramification degree is 3)

Comment: No we chose $f$ so $K$  has degree 3 (see first paragraph)

Comment: Can you explain why the discriminant being a square implies the splitting field is degree 3?

Comment: The discriminant of $f$ is equal to $\prod_{i<j}(r_i-r_j)^2$ where $r_i$ are the roots of $f$. This is a square in $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $\prod_{i<j}(r_i-r_j)$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$. Which permutations $i\mapsto \sigma(i)$ are such that $\prod_{i<j}(r_{\sigma(i)}-r_{\sigma(j)})=\prod_{i<j}(r_i-r_j)$? It is not too hard to convince yourself that $\sigma$ must be even ie in $A_n$. Thus if $f$ is an irreducible cubic with square discriminant the Galois group of the splitting field must lie in $A_3$ and $A_3$ is the cyclic group of order $3$.